# Robust way to generically initialize derived class' fields from base class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I'm working on a project that has a variety of classes that derive from class View, where View provides some common methods and where the derived classes have fields that reference UI elements specific to that view. For example (in C#):

```
public abstract class View
{
   public virtual void Initialize(){}
   public virtual void Activate(){}
   public virtual void Deactivate(){}
}    

public class MainScreenView : View
{
   private ImageView portraitImageView;
   private ImageView landscapeImageView;

   public MainScreenView(ImageView portrait, ImageView landscape)
   {
      portraitImageView = portrait;
      landscapeImageView = landscape;
   }

   public override Initialize()
   {
      base.Initialize();
      portraitImageView.Initialize();   // I would like to eliminate these calls!
      landscapeImageView.Initialize();
   }

   public ImageView GetPortrait() { return portraitImageView; }
   public ImageView GetLandscape() { return landscapeImageView; }
}

public class ImageView : View
{
   private Image image;

   public ImageView(Image image) { this.image = image; }
   public override void Initialize() { base.Initialize(); image.Show(); }
   public Image GetImage() { return image; }
}
```

In this example I have to call Initialize() on all the ImageViews when MainScreenView.Initialize is called. This feels error prone and inconvenient, because an Initialize() call has to be added every time a new sub-view is added to the MainScreenView composition. Therefore, I would like to eliminate the need for these calls in the derived classes, but I want to maintain the fields to the view-specific fields.

My idea is to add a collection of Views to the base class, which can then recursively be Initialized(), as follows:

```
public abstract class View
{
   private List<View> subViews;

   public virtual void Initialize()
   {
      foreach(View in subViews) { view.Initialize(); }
   }

   // This gets called before Initialize() is called.
   public void AddSubViews(View[] views)
   {
      subViews = new List<View>();
      subViews.AddRange(views);
   }
}

public class MainScreenView : View
{
   private ImageView portraitImageView;
   private ImageView landscapeImageView;

   public MainScreenView()
   {
      portraitImageView = ???;
      landscapeImageView = ???;
   }

   // Even if View.subViews had been protected instead of private, this couldn't return an element from the list because the required index is unknown.
   public ImageView GetPortrait() { return portraitImageView; }
   public ImageView GetLandscape() { return landscapeImageView; }
}

public class ImageView : View
{
   private Image image;

   public ImageView() { this.image = ??? }
   public override void Initialize() { base.Initialize(); image.Show(); }
   public Image GetImage() { return image; }   // Even if View.subViews had been protected instead of private, this couldn't return an element from the list because the required index is unknown.
}
```

However, because all the individual sub-views are now 'anonymous' (they are accessed by index instead of a field name), this won't work for me, unless I also add the sub-views through the derived class' constructor as I did in my first example, where I can't enforce that the objects passed to the contructor are the same objects that are in the list, or call AddSubViews from the derived class' constructor where the sub-views are manually added every time a new sub-view is added... which has the same issue as calling Initialize() on sub-views in the derived classes.

So my question is: **is there a way to have all Initialization calls of sub-views being done in the View base class, while still being able to provide derived-class-specific elements without passing references to those elements to the derived class' constructor?**

Comment: Prefer using interfaces (e.g. `IView`) over base abstract classes. You can only derive from a single class in C#, and there is no need to create a dependency to the base abstract class in your entire program. While the `IView` interface will be public, your base class can then be left `internal` and hidden from other assemblies. Also, the fact that each *specific* view will have its own *specific* public methods means that there is no way to actually abstract their usage, so I am not sure how you are planning to use these methods at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: If you want to be sure all sub views are initialized (i.e. nobody forget to add them to base class list of sub views) you can use **reflection** approach. Here is main idea:

```
public interface IView // you don't need abstract class 
{
    void Initialize();
}
```

Use reflection to get all class fields which implement `IView` and was initialized:

```
public class View : IView
{
    private IView portraitView;
    private IView landscapeView;

    // assign some values to sub-views 

    public virtual void Initialize()
    {
        var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        var subViews = from field in GetType().GetFields(flags)
                       let value = field.GetValue(this)
                       where value != null && value is IView
                       select (IView)value;

        foreach (var subView in subViews)
            subView.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Simple as that. Now if anyone will add field of `IView` type to your class it will be initialized with other sub-views.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER: Just add both views to base class subViews list:

```
public MainScreenView(ImageView portrait, ImageView landscape)
{
   portraitImageView = portrait;
   landscapeImageView = landscape;
   AddSubViews(new View [] { portrait, landscape });
}
```

Also keep in mind that you are re-creating subViews list each time when you are trying to *add* new views:

```
public void AddSubViews(View[] views)
{
   subViews = new List<View>(); // here 
   subViews.AddRange(views);
}
```

I believe it's better to create subViews list only once during class field initialization:

```
private readonly List<View> subViews = new List<View>();

public void AddSubViews(params View[] views) // you can use params here
{
   subViews.AddRange(views);
}
```

Now you simply can call

```
AddSubViews(portrait, landscape);
```

Comment: Yes, adding them to the subViews list is something I thought of (as apparently not so clearly mentioned in my question), but when a new subView is added to MainScreenView, the new sub-view has to be added to the parameters list as well. This cannot be enforced and someone can forget to add it to the list, which is something I would like to avoid.

Comment: @Soulrot see updated answer. I used this approach when wrote selenium-based test framework. Self-initialized views were initializing all controls based on class fields

Comment: While I tend to use reflection as a last resort, it is probably the only thing that will achieve what I want, so the updated answer will work for me! In fact I used something very similar in another subsystem, not sure why I didn't think of this approach in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern:

```
public abstract class View
{
    private IEnumerable<View> SubViews { get; }

    protected View(params View[] subViews)
    {
        SubViews = subViews;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        OnInitialize();

        foreach (var view in SubViews)
        {
            view.Initialize();
        }
    }

    protected abstract void OnInitialize();
}
```

Now you concrete views will look like:

```
public class MainScreenView : View
{
    private readonly ImageView portraitImageView;
    private readonly ImageView landscapeImageView;

    public MainScreenView(ImageView portrait, ImageView landscape)
        : base(portrait, landscape)
    {
        portraitImageView = portrait;
        landscapeImageView = landscape;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialize() { }
    public ImageView GetPortrait() { return portraitImageView; }
    public ImageView GetLandscape() { return landscapeImageView; }
}

public class ImageView : View
{
    private readonly Image image;

    public ImageView(Image image)
        : base()
    {
        this.image = image;
    }

    protected override void OnInitialize() { image.Show(); }
    public string GetImage() { return image; }
}
```

And finally,

```
var main = new MainScreenView(new ImageView(portraitImage), new ImageView(landScapeImage));
main.Initialize();
```

will initialize correctly all views.